# how to replace particular text in div with some html using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically what i am looking to do is make this HTML

```
<div id="_EmailBody">
    <p>Hi *|FirstName|*</p>
    <p>My name is B and I am the Account Executive. 
    *|FirstName|*&nbsp;*|LastName|*</p>
</div>
```

Into this using jquery, when the page loads for display

```
<div id="_EmailBody">
   <p>Hi <span class="meta-tag">FirstName</span></p>
   <p>
       My name is B and I am the Account Executive.
       <span class="meta-tag">FirstName</span>&nbsp;<span class="meta-tag">LastName</span>
   </p>
</div>
```

So replace each `*|` with `<span class="meta-tag">`

and each `|*` with `</span>`

What is the best way to achieve this using jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var emailBody = $('#_EmailBody').html();
emailBody = emailBody.replace(/(\*\|)/g, '<span class="meta-tag">');
emailBody = emailBody.replace(/(\|\*)/g, '</span>');   
jQuery('#_EmailBody').html(emailBody);
```

Use jQuery's built in "html" method to get and set the html. Use regex replace to get your desired html from the string.

Comment: Perfect, this solved it. thank you! I will mark it as answer as soon as SO allows me to.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it!